# Comparing decem and -decim

Tags: language-evolution, morphology, numbers, origin

The Latin cardinal numbers starting at ten are *decem, undecim, duodecim…*
Does the *-decim* (roughly "-teen") come from *decem* or from the same root?
(I faintly recall *decem* and *δέκα* coming from something like **dekm*.)
It seems very plausible for semantic reasons and similarity, but I would like to understand the situation better.
**Can someone explain the relation between *decem* and *-decim*?**
Assuming they have a common origin, why does one have E and the other I?
Is this case exceptional?
Are there similar vowel changes in Latin that would help understand this case by analogy?
I can't think of any such vowel changes in the last syllable, or even a short E becoming a short I, so I am really short of other similar examples.
Are there attested spelling variants like *duodecem* that might shed light on the issue?

Comment: Maybe the same kind of apophony that gave us *-cidere* from *cadere* when a preverb is attached? Although it seemed to leave short *e* unchanged: cfr. *perlegere*, *subvenire*...

Comment: @giobrach Possibly. Weakening of a stem vowel before a prefix is not unusual, but I failed to locate more analogous cases (short E to short I, or in the last syllable). I do think this is a part of the same general phenomenon, but I don't see enough context to put it in.

Comment: The *i* seems more common: *ūndecim*, *duodecim*, but also *decimus*; the latter is also attested with *u* > *decumanus*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be a type of metathesis: *undecem > *undicem > undecim. This is apparently irregular, but metathesis often is. I don't know for sure, but I was able to find a source that suggests this, although it indicates that we don't have any attestation of the pre-metathesis form *undicem:

> 12.1.11.1. In Latin 'eleven' to 'seventeen' are all indeclinable compounds of 'one', 'two', etc. and 'ten', which appears as *-decim.* By normal vowel weakening **-decem* > **-dicem,* cf. *auspicem* < **auispecem* acc. sg. to *auspex.* The metathesis must have been due to the combined pressure of *decem* and the ordinals, viz. *decimus : decem :: undecimus : undecim* in place of **undicimus :* **undicem*

(Robert Coleman, 1992. "Italic", Chapter 12 of *[Indo-European Numerals](https://books.google.com/books?id=HmbWRnaridAC&pg=PA396&lpg=PA396&dq=undecim%20metathesis%20undicem&source=bl&ots=JC25Ew4zXj&sig=MOIOG8Qx9urcjp-ZNo3L5jPQRA8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjwsfnL0ofWAhUpxlQKHcRACJ4Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=undecim%20metathesis%20undicem&f=false),* p. 396-397, edited by Jadranka Gvozdanovic)

Coleman seems to indicate that the dating of this hypothesized change from **undicem* > *undecim* is a bit unclear.

Comment: Metathesis never crossed my mind, but it makes sense. To me *decem > dicem > decim* sounds more plausible than a direct *decem > decim*.

Answer (score 3):

De Vaan writes, s.v. "decem":

> In -decim, the i is not well explained. It is often believed to be due
>   to a metathesis of *-dicem > *-decim, but a metathesis of two vowels
>   is extremely rare in IE languages, and hence unlikely. The numerals in
>   decim probably have -dec- from decern 'ten' and -im on the model of
>   the ordinal numbers in -decimus. The ordinal *dekamo- yields decumo-
>   or decimo-, and from it, decumanus is derived.